# search and update within nested array with mongoose

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

simplified schema of a doc in my Model:

```
{
    ar1: [
        {
            b: {
                ar2: [{ _id: 1, value: 2 }],
            },
        },
        {
            b: {
                ar2: [{ _id: 2, value: 2 }],
            },
        },
        {
            b: {
                ar2: [{ _id: 1, value: 5 }],
            },
        },
    ];
}
```

now i want to update all elements of ar2 that have _id equal to 1 so I would obtain:

```
{
    ar1: [
        {
            b: {
                ar2: [{ _id: 1, value: 3 }],
            },
        },
        {
            b: {
                ar2: [{ _id: 2, value: 2 }],
            },
        },
        {
            b: {
                ar2: [{ _id: 1, value: 3 }],
            },
        },
    ];
}
```

The following does not work:

```
Model.updateMany({
    'ar1.b.ar2._id' : 1
},{
    'ar1.$[].b.ar2.$[].value' : 2
});
```

any suggestions ?

The idea is that i want to be able the elements in the nested array that obey the query and update them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [$[]](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/) combine with [$[<identifier>]](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) to do that:

```
Model.update(
  {}, 
  { $set: { "ar1.$[].b.ar2.$[el].value": 3 } },  
  { arrayFilters: [ { "el._id": 1 } ] } 
)
```